# Mac Software to create different versions of an image

Tags: image, resize

I'm looking for a software for mac that I can from one picture generate several versions with predefined sizes:

- max with 300px
- max width 600px
- max width 1200px

Do you know a sw that can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the built-in `sips` command... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584550/bin-bash-terminal-script-to-resize-png-cr2-jpg-images-using-mac-sips-with-space/26587045#26587045

Comment: Thanks ! But I'm looking for a sw that you can generate different versions of an image and not only one.  Define a set of profiles and then generate one image per profile so in the end you have several versions of the same picture. This will be specially useful to generate images that fit specific screen resolutions

Comment: What do you mean by `different versions`? Are the contents the same between the versions? If not, how do they differ? If so, you just mean various sizes and why can't you generate various sizes with `sips`? I don't understand. Maybe some examples would help.

Comment: By different versions I mean different sizes . Let's say one has a max-width of 400px, the 2nd version has a max-height of 600px etc . So can you in sips specify different sizes and generate all of them at once ? from what I've read in the script it only generates one version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use OSX's built-in `sips`.

Start with a 2048x1536 image, copy it and resize copy to 300px wide

```
cp input.png 300.png
sips --resampleWidth 300 300.png      # ==> 300x225 image
```

copy and resize the copy to 600ox

```
cp input.png 600.png
sips --resampleWidth 600 600.png      # ==> 600x450 image
```

copy and resize to 1200px

```
cp input.png 1200.png
sips --resampleWidth 1200 1200.png    # ==> 1200x900 image
```